# Downgrade ubuntu kernel for azure migration

Tags: server, kernel

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS kernel 5.11.0-43-generic and azure migration mobility service support 5.4 version. What will happen if I downgrade my kernel version, as my site is working on kernel 5.11.
[OS and kernel version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxSOV.png)

Comment: You've not provided your OS & release; the 5.11 kernel is easily downgraded if you're using a LTS release (refer to doco; switch from HWE to GA stack) but that may not apply if you're not using a LTS release.   You can have both kernel stacks installed (HWE & GA) so you can compare (*though only one can be used at a time*), but details depend on your *unstated* release.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, updated the os

Comment: FYI:  if you look it won't be 20.04.2, as that used the 5.8 kernel; you've likely upgraded to 20.04.3 thus the 5.11 HWE kernel.   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  provides details on installing/switching from HWE kernel stack to GA